# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext issue in Spring boot 1.5.9 and OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

i was trying out with the sample application Spring Boot REST API Security with OAuth2 from 
https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html and it works fine, the sample uses spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE, but when i switch to 1.5.9.RELEASE, i get this Authentication object not found issue. i have searched online for an answer and couldn't come up with anything close to resolve the issue. some people say that the order of filter chain is the cause. but none seem to be able to come up with a solution.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

adding the @Order annotation resolve the issue. now i can use 1.5.9.RELEASE. I found it from https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server